# External USB hard disk not seen in device window

Tags: disk

I am attempting to format an external hard drive in Linux (as opposed to Mac or PC).  I am running the Ubuntu Linux 14.04 desktop on my MacBook pro through Parrallels.  When I click the Dash button, and then disks, my internal hard drive shows up under devices but any USB  external hard drives connected to the Mac do not, even though it is visible in my laptop window. So,

1. Can I format a hard drive in Linux?
2. Is there a way of seeing this hard drive listed under "devices" in Ubuntu?
3. Since I'm not a programmer or computer tech is there a simple answer which doesn't require using the command lines.

The reason for a Linux format is that movie theaters require picture and sound files to be sent on a Linux formatted hard drive. Mac formatting is a single click on the disk utilities app.  I have yet to find a simple way of creating a Linux formatted disk. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have to enable the USB device in Parallels.

Answer (score -1):

Try installing gparted from the software center (or via command line with `sudo apt-get install gparted`). Gparted is a very powerful partitioning program which can format drives in many different ways through a simple graphical interface.

Comment: If Disks not see the drive, than gparted is also useless

Comment: Oops. Didn't read close enough, I didn't realise it was a virtual machine, just that they were asking how to format a drive in linux.